# PHPMyAdmin Error - "The server is not responding"

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I encountered a problem when accessing the PHPMyAdmin on WAMP. The database can not be opened, and there is an error message as shown below:

> Error
>   MySQL said:
>
> #2003 - The server is not responding

Please kindly assist, and advise if there is any configuration that should be done.
Thanks.

Comment: Recheck your configuration settings. Are they correct? Server host, server port, username, password, database name. If you have SSH access, try it on the command line. Put the code you use here (without the real password, etc)

Comment: exactly, have you consulted the docs at http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/ ?

Answer (score 0):

## Completely remove your php and phpmyadmin :

1. sudo dpkg -P phpmyadmin
2. sudo rm -f /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf
3. sudo service apache2 restart
4. sudo apt-get purge php.*
5. sudo service apache2 restart

## Then Install php 7.0 :

1. sudo apt-get install php7.0 php7.0-fpm php7.0-mysql -y

## Fianlly, Install phpmyadmin :

1. sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin

***sudo apt-get enjoy :)**